# Solving recurrence T(n) = T(n - 1) + n^2 substitution method

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence, algebra

I am trying to solve a recurrence using substitution method (I am asking for help/confirmation about this solving method, so don't answer with a solution developed by iteration method or something else).
I want to precise that I have just started studying recurrence relations, so I am asking for confirmation of my work.

[image: The recurrence]

I guess that T(n) = O(n^3), so:
[image]

then I continued like this:
[image]

from now on, this is the part about I am not sure if I did it right:
[image]
Now, I am not sure if i did that right.
I know that this recurrence is a O(n^3), but I want to know if my proof is true.
I want to say that this isn't a homework or something like that, it's a simple exercise that came up to my mind.

Comment: makes sense, think you can choose c=1/3 for any n and thus T in O(n^3)
Why is this method called substitution method?

Comment: I see, I was afraid about this proof and I'm still thinking that something is missing.
Have I used the substitution method correctly or have I made any mistakes?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a mathematics question not a computer programming question.